# i want to add and remove active class to my navigation on scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add and remove active class to my navigation on jquery scroll function i made a script,but it is adding active class but not reomve it

```
jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    var row = jQuery('#about-btn'), scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 750)
    {   
        row.addClass('active');
    }
    else if (scrollTop == 800)
    {
        row.removeClass('active');
    }
});
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script remove class "active" only if scroll is exact at 800px.

Try replace

```
if(scrollTop > 750)
```

with

```
if(scrollTop > 750 && scrollTop <= 799)
```

***and***

this

```
else if (scrollTop == 800)
```

with

```
if (scrollTop >= 800)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you only remove the class if the `scrollTop` value is *exactly* `800px`, which is a very small target to hit. Even more so when you consider that the browser doesn't update for every pixel scrolled and can miss some out.

To fix this, make the conditions in the `if` statement use a range. I'd also suggest you select the `#about-btn` element *outside* of the scroll handler. Try this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
  var $row = $('#about-btn');

  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $row.toggleClass('active', scrollTop > 750 && scrollTop < 800);
  });
});
```